# Need to verify my disprove about a statement about big O

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics, solution-verification

$f, g: ℝ+ → ℝ+.$
Prove or disprove:
$f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(g(n)f(n))$

My try:
Let us assume the theorem holds true. By definition, we get that:
$$⇒ f(n) + g(n) ≤ cg(n)f(n)$$
dividing both sides by $g(n)f(n)$:

$$\frac{1}{f\left(n\right)}+\frac{1}{g\left(n\right)}\le c$$
Now, consider $g(n) = f(n) = 0.5^n$
with the domain of $n > 0$. Subsituting:
$$\frac{1}{0.5^n}+\frac{1}{0.5^n}\le c$$
Now, take the $\lim _{n\to \infty }$ of both sides, we get that:
$$\infty \le c$$
and this is a contradiction since infinity is bigger than any real number. And thus, our initial assumption that $f(n)+g(n)∈O(g(n)f(n))$ is false.
Is my proof valid?

Comment: Might want to fix an $n$ which is bigger then $c$, like $n =\log_2(c+2)$.

Comment: Can you be more clear please?

Comment: The use of the limit is unnecessarily complicated. Just disproving the “for every” at one point is enough, such as the point I previously mentioned.

Comment: It's much clearer to present your proof as "this theorem is not true. Let $f(x) = g(x) = 1/2^x$..." and show that these are a counterexample to the theorem. The format of proof by contradiction doesn't really get you anything here. Also you could expand a bit on the step where you say $f(n) + g(n) \le cg(n) f(n)$. Where did $c$ come from? Is this true for any $n$? If you've met little-oh, you could shorten your proof a bit by using it.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right Izaak. About the little o, would it also be valid if I show that $f(n)+g(n)$ is actually omega  of $g(n)*f(n)$?

Comment: Another example is $f(x)=g(x)=1/x. $  This example also shows that $f(n)+g(n)\in o(f(n)g(n))$ can be false. BTW, be careful with the def'ns of $O$ and $o$..... $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ as $n\to \infty$ does NOT mean $\exists c>0\,\forall n\,(|f(n)|\le c |g(n)|\,).$ It means $\exists c>0\, \exists m\, \forall n>m\,(|f(n)\le c|g(n)|\,).$